# $variable OR $variable = $variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, syntax

This is a standalone expression in a function:

```
$var OR $var = $var
```

What does this expression exactly do?

Never saw this before and can't find the answer as I have no idea how is this called.

Code itself is from: [Сodeigniter Template on Github](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template/blob/master/libraries/Template.php)

```
public function build($view, $data = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    // Set whatever values are given. These will be available to all view files
    is_array($data) OR $data = (array) $data;
    // Merge in what we already have with the specific data
    $this->_data = array_merge($this->_data, $data);

...
```

Comment: I'd say that it does nothing relevant... can we see the function?

Comment: Is `$var` supposed to be in the code 3 times?

Comment: Assignment (`=`) has higher precedence than `OR`, so it sets a variable value to itself, and then ors it with itself again, and then does absolutely nothing.... it's basically a waste of processing cycles as it stands

Comment: `is_array($data) OR $data = (array) $data;` doesn't do the same thing of `$var OR $var = $var`. Why didn't you post that from the start?

Comment: it's equivalent to `if (!is_array($data)) { $data = (array) $data; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an expression like yours

```
is_array($data) OR $data = (array) $data;
```

we check the precedence table on http://php.net/operators.precedence first. There we see `=` is above `OR`. Thus the line is equal to this:

```
is_array($data) OR ($data = (array) $data);
```

Next we have to check the table for associativity. `or` is left associative so it checks `is_array($data)`. If that returns `true` the `or`expression as a whole returns `true`and nothing else happens.

If `is_array($data)` returns `false` we have to evaluate further, so `$data = (array) $data` is executed.

In the end this is a "smart" way to write

```
if (!is_array($data)) {
    $data = (array) $data;
}
```

Actually in this specific case we could also write only

```
$data = (array) $data;
```

As the `(array)` cast is a no-op if `$data` already is an array.